# Inheritance with @Controller in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I would like have a @Controller parent in my app, as this:

```
@Controller
public class controllerParent{

public String getUser (Model model,HttpServletRequest request){  
  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();        
  String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username         
  user = userService.findByUserName(name);                                 
  model.addAttribute("user",user);
 }
}
```

and a child:

```
public class chil extends controllerParent{

 @RequestMapping(value="/something.html",method = RequestMethod.GET)    
 public String doSomething (Model model,HttpServletRequest request){    
     //Code to do something          
 }
```

}

And what want to do is that in each child controller call I want show in my JSP the user . Can I do this without rewrite spring security code?

Comment: Have you tried what you have showed? What is the problem with it?

Comment: No, I' m sorry, I haven't tried it yet. it is just a question, about if is possible to do it. I have an application, and I repeat the same code in every controller, and I just thought if is possible to do that.

Comment: I am almost certain that you will need to remove `@Controller` from the `parentController` and add it to each child. Other than that, your example should work just fine. Give it a shot and let me know so I can add it as an answer

Comment: thank you geoadan, I'll try it this evening.